# Dual boot windows 10 and Kali Linux unusual problems

Tags: windows, kali-linux, dual-boot

So I just made a 70GB partition on my 1TB ssd by using the Kali Linux live CD.
After I installed everything, the system booted into Kali just fine, with no problems. Although, when I try to restart and boot into windows it does not show me a windows 10 option. I can actually boot into windows 10 if I go into my BIOS and make sure it is set to UEFI. If I set it to CSM (I guess that's an older bios compatibility thing), it boots Kali Linux with no problem.

So both operating systems will boot, but I do not have a simple way to switch between them.

Are there any fixes for this?

EDIT: I installed Kali onto the 70gb partition on the ssd, not onto the CD

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure that Kali linux support UEFI, but you must install it when UEFI is turned on in bios. Also, you must turn off secure boot in bios.